# How to construct a function call to pmax from the columns of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I want to use `pmax` to compute the row-wise maximium of a matrix `A`:

```
A = matrix(sample(1:20),10,2)
pmax(A[,1],A[,2])
```

this works fine. But the problem is that I don't know the size of A, so the call to `pmax` should be able to split the matrix by columns and supply each column as an argument. how to do that? For example, I may in the next instance have

```
A = matrix(sample(1:20),5,4)
```

But I don't want to have to rewrite by hand every time to

```
pmax(A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4])
```

in fact, I can't because the size of `A` is unknown before the start of the program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `do.call`:

```
do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(A))
```

Comment: @FlorianOswald It should be noted that this will be faster when you have rows >> columns, and slower when you have columns >> rows, than the `apply` usage which is designed to work with matrices.

Comment: @SimonO101 I put up a [gist with my benchmark](https://gist.github.com/floswald/5600138). what you say is correct. the speed difference between pmax and C is smallest for rows>>columns. for columns>>rows, apply is still much slower than C.

Comment: @FlorianOswald Yes, I know it will be slower than C! As is `pmax` right. I was talking about the difference between `max` and `pmax` because you were talking about not using `apply` for performance reasons, as though `pmax` could be better than C.

Comment: @SimonO101 that is fair enough, what you said is well taken. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `apply` with `max` instead...

```
apply( A , 1 , max )
# [1]  6 11 20 18 17

pmax(A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4])
# [1]  6 11 20 18 17
```

Comment: I want to avoid apply because of performance reasons. I do that on a very big matrix. I've written an RcppArmadillo function to substitute for `apply` and it's 18 times faster. Now wanted to benchmark against `pmax`. I know that there the C code is 3 times faster, but `pmax` is able to do `na.rm` which I have to do separately in C. That's where I'm coming from.

Comment: Faster than the C code? Well, I've tried it out: it's not. (it's much slower).